# Making custom JsonConverter respect ItemTypeNameHandling when serializing with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have an object with a list of base class sub-objects. Sub-objects need a custom converter. I can't make my custom converter respect `ItemTypeNameHandling` option.

Sample code (create a new C# Console project, add JSON.NET NuGet package):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace My {
    class Program {
        private static void Main () {
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                new Box { toys = { new Spintop(), new Ball() } },
                Formatting.Indented));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    [JsonObject] class Box
    {
        [JsonProperty (
            ItemConverterType = typeof(ToyConverter),
            ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)]
        public List<Toy> toys = new List<Toy>();
    }
    [JsonObject] class Toy {}
    [JsonObject] class Spintop : Toy {}
    [JsonObject] class Ball : Toy {}

    class ToyConverter : JsonConverter {
        public override void WriteJson (JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }
        public override object ReadJson (JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        }
        public override bool CanConvert (Type objectType) {
            return typeof(Toy).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        }
    }
}
```

Produced output:

```
{
  "toys": [
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```

Necessary output (this is what happens if I comment `ItemConverterType = typeof(ToyConverter),` line):

```
{
  "toys": [
    {
      "$type": "My.Spintop, Serialization"
    },
    {
      "$type": "My.Ball, Serialization"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried temporarily changing value of `serializer.TypeNameHandling` in `ToyConverter.WriteJson` method, but it affects unrelated properties. (Of course, my real converter is more complex than that. It's just an example with base functionality.)

**Question:** How to make my custom `JsonConverter` respect `ItemTypeNameHandling` property of `JsonProperty` attribute?

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: And what I say is you don't need a TypeConvertor, to achieve serialization/deserialization of sub types of Toy. You can also try to read and understand the answers carefully. I'll delete my answer. Seems you already know everything and don't need any help.

Comment: @I4V I need a custom converter for other purposes, unrelated with "$type".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having delved into the source code for Json.Net (version 4.5 release 11), it looks as though what you want to do is not possible.

The key to getting types written to the output is this method:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter
    .ShouldWriteType(TypeNameHandling typeNameHandlingFlag, JsonContract contract,
        JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract,
        JsonProperty containerProperty)
```

It's the `containerContract` and `containerProperty` parameters that are important here. When serializing *without* a converter, these parameters are supplied and `ShouldWriteType` is able to use them to figure out what `TypeNameHandling` to use.

When serializing *with* a converter, however, those two parameters are not supplied. This appears to be because `ToyConverter.WriteJson` results in a call to `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue` like this:

```
SerializeValue(jsonWriter, value, GetContractSafe(value), null, null, null);
```

Note that the last two parameters are in fact a `JsonContainerContract containerContract` and `JsonProperty containerProperty`, and are passed down the chain to the `ShouldWriteType` method. Therein lies the problem: because they are null, the logic of the `ShouldWriteType` method means that it returns `false`, thus the type is not written.

**Edit:**

Inspired by [this](http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization), you could workaround this problem by customising the `WriteJson` method of your converter:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    writer.WriteStartObject();
    writer.WritePropertyName("$type");
    writer.WriteValue(RemoveAssemblyDetails(value.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName.ToString()));
    writer.WriteEndObject();
}

private static string RemoveAssemblyDetails(string fullyQualifiedTypeName)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    // loop through the type name and filter out qualified assembly details from nested type names
    bool writingAssemblyName = false;
    bool skippingAssemblyDetails = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < fullyQualifiedTypeName.Length; i++)
    {
        char current = fullyQualifiedTypeName[i];
        switch (current)
        {
            case '[':
                writingAssemblyName = false;
                skippingAssemblyDetails = false;
                builder.Append(current);
                break;
            case ']':
                writingAssemblyName = false;
                skippingAssemblyDetails = false;
                builder.Append(current);
                break;
            case ',':
                if (!writingAssemblyName)
                {
                    writingAssemblyName = true;
                    builder.Append(current);
                }
                else
                {
                    skippingAssemblyDetails = true;
                }
                break;
            default:
                if (!skippingAssemblyDetails)
                    builder.Append(current);
                break;
        }
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Note that that `RemoveAssemblyDetails` method is ripped straight from the Json.Net [source](http://json.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/69709#128141).

You will of course need to modify the `WriteJson` method to output the rest of the fields, but hopefully that does the trick.

Comment: Can you suggest any workarounds? Or maybe I should report it as a bug/feature request? :)

Comment: Your solution suggests rewriting the whole serialization from scratch using low-level API. Obviously, I don't want to do everything manually. Well, I guess the only option left is to do tricks with JObjects... I'll try to get in contact with the library author.

Comment: True enough, but that is kind of the point of using a converter ;). Out of interest, do you need to use one? I get the feeling the task you are actually undertaking is far trickier than what's in your question. If you want to post some more details, I am happy to look into this some more.

Comment: I've customized reading, but I don't need to customize writing. And this is why: [Serializing heavily linked data in .NET (customizing JSON.NET references)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108693/serializing-heavily-linked-data-in-net-customizing-json-net-references) (see `JsonRefedConverter` class in the answer). Posted an issue on CodePlex: [Custom JsonConverter does not respect ItemTypeNameHandling option](http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/23794)

Comment: You have two errors in the code :              
         case ',':
                if (!writingAssemblyName)
                {
                    writingAssemblyName = true;
                    ...
should be:
         case ',':
                if (writingAssemblyName)  // remove !
                {
                    writingAssemblyName = false;  // change to false
                    ...

Test and you will find this now actually does remove the assembly name! :)