# Error in Convert Dynamic Type In Costume Class In JSon Serializer C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, dynamictype

I Have a Interface that Implemented By many Class, In My Interface i have a Class that fill by child class that Implemented my Interface.
my work is , i find the class that Implement My Interface and call the class that filled, then i Serialize that classes by NewSoft.Json and write to file then in another place i deserialize that file and create instance of my root class and pass it to the classes that want to read and use it.
my problem is when i deserialize  and fill in my proprties, i cant use my Data Proprties because json cant give me the right thing.

for Example in my test Scenario i have a class that fill my class proprties and file DataTable in Data Proprties then i Serialize it and when i deserialize ir and want to convert it to datatable again have some error
i Get type of Data Proprties and say is Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray
and my other question is how to write the common code that can convert all of the type the classes fill it befor
My Code is Blow :

my Interface :

```
 public interface ISyncable
        {
            List<SyncablePackage> GetSyncableEntityDetails();
            void SetSyncablePackage(SyncablePackage syncablepackage);
            List<Guid> DependentSoftwares { get; set; }
        }
```

My Class :

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class SyncablePackage : ISerializable,IDisposable
{
    public SyncablePackage() { }
    public SyncablePackage(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        //Get the values from info and assign them to the appropriate properties
        EntityGuid = (Guid)info.GetValue("EntityGuid", typeof(Guid));
        Name = (string)info.GetValue("Name", typeof(string));
        Data = (object)info.GetValue("Data", typeof(object));
        DataFileID = (List<int>)info.GetValue("DataFileID", typeof(List<int>));
    }
    //Serialization function.
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        info.AddValue("EntityGuid", EntityGuid);
        info.AddValue("Name", Name);
        info.AddValue("Data", Data);
        info.AddValue("DataFileID", DataFileID);
    }

    [DataMember]
    public Guid EntityGuid;
    [DataMember]
    public string Name;
    [DataMember]
    public object Data;
    [DataMember]
    public List<int> DataFileID;

    [DataMember]
    private IntPtr handle = new IntPtr();
    [DataMember]
    private Component component = new Component();
    [DataMember]
    private bool disposed = false;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                Name = null;
                Data = null;
                DataFileID = null;
                component.Dispose();
            }
            CloseHandle(handle);
            handle = IntPtr.Zero;
            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Kernel32")]
    private extern static Boolean CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
    ~SyncablePackage()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

}
```

the sample class fill data 
then i get it and serialize it like blow :

```
#region Handle Null Value
                    if (package.DataFileID == null)
                        package.DataFileID = new List<int>() { int.MinValue };
                    if (package.Data == null)
                        package.Data = new DataTable();
                    if (package.Name == null)
                        package.Name = "NoName";
                    if (package.EntityGuid == null)
                        package.EntityGuid = Guid.Empty;
                    #endregion

                    using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(fileName))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            stream.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                            stream.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(package));
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            stream.BaseStream.Flush();
                            stream.Close();
                            stream.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
```

in other place i get the file and use like this :

```
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(fileName))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            stream.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat };
                            var sss = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SyncablePackage>(stream.ReadToEnd(), settings);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            stream.BaseStream.Flush();
                            stream.Close();
                            stream.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
```

and i get data in file  :

```
{"EntityGuid":"4a6e20fd-e0c1-451b-870d-645162cbae60","Name":"AccessZones","Data":[{"ID":13,"Code":"23","Title":"(3)","Active":false,"Deleted":true,"Guid":"bdbc92c4-4246-4695-b36c-49b4911d7abe","ModificationDate":"2015-01-05T17:25:59.763","ModificationServerGuid":"33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333"},{"ID":15,"Code":"21","Title":" (2)","Active":false,"Deleted":true,"Guid":"b304aed4-d175-4d69-91ae-b98176e471f4","ModificationDate":"2015-01-05T17:25:59.763","ModificationServerGuid":"33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333"},{"ID":16,"Code":"22","Title":" (3)","Active":false,"Deleted":true,"Guid":"cdc03816-83e8-41dc-bd43-2681a3e3438c","ModificationDate":"2015-01-05T17:25:59.763","ModificationServerGuid":"33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333"}],"DataFileID":[-2147483648]}
```

can anyone tell me what i forgot ?

Comment: Your class is extremely complex, most of which is not required to reproduce the problem.  For future questions, I suggest trying to create a [minimal class that still reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your classes implement `ISerializable`.  Are you also doing binary serialization with [`BinaryFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @dbc : tnx for your replay, yes i use binaryformatter but the problem of that is use lot of memory and the memory growth during the time. my code like that : private readonly static BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();                                                               using (FileStream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create))
     {
      try
      {
       bformatter.Serialize(stream, package);
      }
      finally
      {
       if (stream != null)
       {
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Close();
        stream.Dispose();
       }
      }
     }

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arises because you have declared `Data` as an `object` rather than its actual type:

```
public object Data;
```

When Json.NET tries to deserialize such a field, it has no information about the desired type, so deserializes it as a `JToken` (which is of course a subclass of `object`) to hold the data read from the file.

The simplest fix is to declare `Data` as its actual type:

```
public DataTable Data { get; set; }
```

If you can't do this (because e.g. you are actually using a typed table from a [typed `DataSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wha85tzb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) whose type might vary in runtime), the *normal* solution would be to set [`TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm).  However, this doesn't work for `DataTable` because `DataTable` is stored via a converter, [`DataTableConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_DataTableConverter.htm) -- and converters [do not work with type name handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182961/making-custom-jsonconverter-respect-itemtypenamehandling-when-serializing-with-j).

The solution to this is to create an intermediate generic proxy object that does not require a converter and can hold the type information:

```
public abstract class JsonTypeWrapper
{
    protected JsonTypeWrapper() { }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public abstract object ObjectValue { get; }

    public static object CreateWrapper<T>(T value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return new JsonTypeWrapper<T>();
        var type = value.GetType();
        if (type == typeof(T))
            return new JsonTypeWrapper<T>(value);
        // Return actual type of subclass
        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(JsonTypeWrapper<>).MakeGenericType(type), value);
    }
}

[DataContract]
public sealed class JsonTypeWrapper<T> : JsonTypeWrapper
{
    public JsonTypeWrapper() : base() { }

    public JsonTypeWrapper(T value) : base()
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public override object ObjectValue
    {
        get { return Value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

And then use it in your class like so:

```
[DataContract]
public partial class SyncablePackage 
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public object Data;

    [DataMember(Name="Data")]
    [JsonProperty("Data", TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)] // REQUIRE output of type information.
    object DataWrapper
    {
        get
        {
            if (Data == null)
                return null;
            return JsonTypeWrapper.CreateWrapper(Data);
        }
        set
        {
            var wrapper = value as JsonTypeWrapper;
            if (wrapper == null)
            {
                if (value != null)
                    Debug.WriteLine("Invalid incoming data type: " + value.ToString());
                Data = null;
                return;
            }
            Data = wrapper.ObjectValue;
        }
    }
}
```

And the JSON produced would look something like:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "$type": "MyNamespace.JsonTypeWrapper`1[[MyNamespace.MyDataSetType+MyDataTableType, MyAssemblyName]], MyAssemblyName",
    "Value": [
      {
        "Value": "2015-03-07T05:00:00Z"
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

**Update**

Just noticed you're *also* using `ISerializable` which makes things more complex, because `JsonPropertyAttribute` does not work with `ISerializable`.  Instead, you must force serialization of the `$type` property in `GetObjectData` and in the streaming constructor:

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public partial class SyncablePackage : ISerializable
{
    public SyncablePackage() { }

    public SyncablePackage(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        var jObj = (JObject)info.GetValue("Data", typeof(JObject));
        if (jObj != null)
            DataWrapper = jObj.ToObject<object>(new JsonSerializer { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
        Name = (string)info.GetValue("Name", typeof(string)); // Serialize your other properties as needed.
    }

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Data", JObject.FromObject(DataWrapper, new JsonSerializer { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }));
        info.AddValue("Name", Name); // Deserialize your other properties as needed.
    }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public object Data;

    [DataMember(Name = "Data")]
    object DataWrapper
    {
        get
        {
            if (Data == null)
                return null;
            return JsonTypeWrapper.CreateWrapper(Data);
        }
        set
        {
            var wrapper = value as JsonTypeWrapper;
            if (wrapper == null)
            {
                if (value != null)
                    Debug.WriteLine("Invalid incoming data type: " + value.ToString());
                Data = null;
                return;
            }
            Data = wrapper.ObjectValue;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

If you're also using the same code for binary serialization, you will need to ensure `ISerializable.GetObjectData` and `public SyncablePackage(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)` work the old way when doing binary formatting - despite being used for both binary formatting and JSON formatting.  You can use [`StreamingContext.Context`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.streamingcontext.context%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to signal to these methods that JSON is being serialized:

```
/// <summary>
/// Synthetic class to set in StreamingContext.Context
/// </summary>
public sealed class JsonStreamingContext
{
    public JsonStreamingContext()
    {
    }
}

[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public partial class SyncablePackage : ISerializable
{
    public SyncablePackage() { }

    public SyncablePackage(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        if (ctxt.Context is JsonStreamingContext)
        {
            var jObj = (JObject)info.GetValue("Data", typeof(JObject));
            if (jObj != null)
                DataWrapper = jObj.ToObject<object>(new JsonSerializer { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
        }
        else
        {
            Data = (object)info.GetValue("Data", typeof(object));
        }
        Name = (string)info.GetValue("Name", typeof(string)); // Serialize your other properties as needed.
    }

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Context is JsonStreamingContext)
        {
            info.AddValue("Data", JObject.FromObject(DataWrapper, new JsonSerializer { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }));
        }
        else
        {
            info.AddValue("Data", Data);
        }

        info.AddValue("Name", Name); // Deserialize your other properties as needed.
    }

    // Rest as in first update.
}
```

Then serialize by setting a `JsonStreamingContext` in [`JsonSerializerSettings.Context.Context`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Context.htm):

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All, new JsonStreamingContext()) };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(package, settings);

        var package = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SyncablePackage>(json, settings);
```

Comment: @AlirezaSix - answer updated with a suggestion about how to update your `ISerializable` methods code for JSON serialization while leaving binary formatting unchanged.

Comment: dear @dbc : i use your sample and test it (i remove Iserializble from my class and use DataConteract) and i got this error : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error resolving type specified in JSON 'Chargoon.Didgah.Framework.Synchronization.JsonTypeWrapper`1[[System.Data.DataTable, System.Data]], Chargoon.Didgah.Framework'. Path 'Data.$type', line 4, position 140. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not find type 'Chargoon.Didgah.Framework.Synchronization.JsonTypeWrapper`1[[System.Data.DataTable, System.Data]]' in assembly 'Chargoon.Didgah.Framework, Version=4.90.

Comment: my reason to use object type in Data Proprties is that other solution use my class (in dll) and pass any type to class (DataTable,DataSet,Generic Type, CUstome Type) and i have to get the data and Serialize it and transfer it via net to other server and in secount server i must desrialize it an pass to other class the same data that gave it to me

Comment: @AlirezaSix - I can't reproduce your problem using a client only.  It sounds like you have the same problem as here: [handling name space changes during deserialization of JSON String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124179/handling-name-space-changes-during-deserialization-of-json-string/28125077).  In order for `TypeNameHandling` to work, you must either extract a DLL with the shared classes and use it in both the client and server, or remap the DLL and/or namespace names as needed as shown in the linked answer.

Comment: i change my serializer to xmlserializer and cache it then when i want to serialize check the cache if exists use it else create new instance . my problem is less but my not resolve. however tnx for answer ;)